# Extension method information from Roslyn

Tags: roslyn

I am trying to using Roslyn to extract various method call information from a give source file. To elaborate - I want to find all method invocations that happen inside the input file.

One problem I am hitting is to do with extension methods. Consider any `Linq` method like `Aggregate`, `Sum` etc. How can I figure out from an `InvocationExpressionSyntax` that the method being invoked is an extension method and not a simple member method of the class.

The source file I input can be expected to compile - meaning that `GetDiagnostics()` will not have any errors.

---- Some code to get to the property mentioned by @Kevin in his answer ----

```
var methodInfo = model.GetSymbolInfo(invocation);
if (methodInfo.Symbol != null)
{
    var mSymbol = (IMethodSymbol)methodInfo.Symbol;
    if (mSymbol.ReducedFrom != null)
    {
        // this is an extension method !
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the actual static extension method for an instance invocation of an extension method using the `IMethodSymbol.ReducedFrom` property.